# Passing a value coming from a session to font-size attribute

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2, ognl

I need your help in order to solve a question. I need to set the font size according to a value I stored into a session. 
I need to write something similar to

```xml
<a href="/chips" style="font-size: (#session.soglia)pt"><s:property value="nome"/></a>
```

but this does not work! How can I do? The font size is stored into a session because it can dinamically change (an action class calculates it before calling the jsp page). Thank you!!!

Comment: Write the text to the jsp output using variable from the value stack, OGNL is used for but any reason to change the style dynamically? It would be hard to change the markup in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The font size is stored into a session because it can dinamically change (an action class calculates it before calling the jsp page).

This does not explain why the session is needed here, but however...

to access a Session attribute, an Action attribute or whatever with OGNL, you need to use Struts Tags.

```xml
<a href="/chips" style="font-size: <s:property value='#session.soglia'/>pt">
    <s:property value="nome"/>
</a>
```

Otherwise you'd need to use JSP EL. But don't.

Off-topic: it's worth noting that today we have more proficient ways to handle font sizes than points, eg. with [Viewport Sized typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have used a session because I have stored some objects. I need to retrieve an integer value from the session because an action class calculates it before calling the corresponding jsp page. The font size dinamically changes because the number of items and words changes too...:)

Comment: @AlessandroPietra sure, but why that *action class [that] calculates it before calling the corresponding jsp* does not store it in an action attribute instead that in the session ? It doesn't seem mandatory here. BTW if you liked the answer please consider accepting and upvoting it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i can store that value into an action attribute as well. Thanks again! :)

Comment: It does not work...I have declared an int variable inside my action class, together with get and set mothods. Then in my jsp page i write...

<a href="/chips" style="font-size: <s:property value="fontsize"/>pt"><s:property value="nome"/></a>

but the size doesn't change....for example i tried to set fonsize=300 in my action class...

Comment: What do you see in the  generated html by clicking View Source ? BTW edit your question with the new code (variable, getter and setter and every other relevant detail)

Comment: My action class is...
    public class TagCloud implements SessionAware  {
 private int fontsize;
        //some code
        get and set methods related to fontsize
     } 

     the execute method calls this jsp code. I see the page, so the file   struts.xml is correct and i do not post it..

<div id="tags">
    <ul>
    <s:iterator value="%{#session.TAGS_TWITTER}">
    <s:if test="%{frequenza > 0}">
    <li><a style="font-size:<s:property value='fontsize'/>pt"><s:property value="nome"/></a></li>
 </s:if>

Comment: Sure. Now, what do you see in the GENERATED html by clicking View Source ? Also why `<s:property value='fontsize'/>`, wasn't it `<s:property value='soglia'/>` ?

Comment: This is the code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-DhQ3bK7YfeTUVmS2M3Z2lVaGc/view?usp=sharing
you don't see 'soglia' because I haven't used a session as you told me before. I have used a new action attribute.

Comment: i think it's a view problem related to the script "tagcloud/tagcanvas.min.js". I tried to open the html code and the list is created with the correct size (in this case 300pt).